# Why is the first iteration always faster then the next in a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

I would like to understand why the `first iteration` in the **loop** executes quicker than the rest.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch ();
sw.Start ();

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep ( 100 );
   Console.WriteLine ( "Finished at : {0}", ((double) sw.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency ) * 1e3 );
}
```

When I execute the code I get the following:

[image]

Initially I thought it could be due to the accuracy factor of [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but then why is it applicable only to the first element? Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: hardly that much slower is it?

Comment: it's actually a jump and incrementation executed each step except first.

Comment: I don't really see a difference.  Each iteration through the loop is about 100ms!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very flawed benchmark. For one, `Thread.Sleep` does not guarantee you that you'll sleep for exactly 100ms. Try much longer sleeps and you'll see more consistent results.

So it might be even just scheduling - the next iterations are always just doing sleep after sleep. Since `Sleep` works thanks to the system interrupt clock, the sleeps after the first should take similar amount of time, while the first has to "sync up" with the clock first.

If you add another sleep *before* the cycle (and before starting the stopwatch), you'll likely get closer times for each of the iterations.

Or even better, don't use sleeps. If you use some actual CPU work instead, you'll avoid thread switches (provided you've got enough CPU to do that) and many other costs not associated with the cycle itself. For example,

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch ();
sw.Start ();

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   Thread.SpinWait(10000000);

   Console.WriteLine ( "Finished at : {0}", ((double) sw.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency ) * 1e3 );
}
```

This will give you much more consistent results, because it doesn't depend on the clock at all.

There's many other things that can complicate a benchmark like this, which is why benchmarks simply aren't done this way. There will always be deviations, and they can get rather big, especially on a system with a lot of work.

In other words, if you're getting differences in CPU work execution time on the scale of milliseconds, someone is stealing your work. There's nothing in a modern CPU that would account for such a huge difference just based on e.g. `i++` being there or not.

I could describe a lot more issues with your code, but it probably isn't worth it. Just google for some best practices on CPU work benchmarking in C#, and you'll get much more worth out of it.

Oh, and just to help hammer the point home more, on my computer, the first tends to go anywhere from `99` up to `100`. This would be highly unusual, since the default is `15.6ms`, rather than `1ms`, but the culprit is easily found - Chrome sets it to `1ms`. Ouch.

Comment: This is *NOT* the reason why above code is giving the results it is giving.. It is because the `Stopwatch` is not being reset.. it just keeps adding more and more time to elapsed time from all previous iterations... iteration values `100,200,300,400,500...` clearly indicate that.. The answer that it is due to accuracy of Sleep etc and timer resolution do *not* apply here at all.

Comment: @VikasGupta Wait, you think that the OP didn't figure *that* out? He singled out the *first* iteration specifically, not that each of the iterations after that are slower and slower. We're talking about a difference of under a millisecond, not hundreds.

Comment: I may not be reading what you are reading in the question.. I did read it again.. If your interpretation is right, San can tell.. and the test output along with the question is certainly misleading to me.

Comment: @Vikas, apologies if I wasn't clear... Luaan's right. my concern was with the first iteration & not the remaining ones.

Answer (score 3):

What you're outputting for times is the *total* time elapsed since the start.  so, time increasing by about 100ms is exactly what you should be expecting

But, when you use `Thread.Sleep` you're giving up control of the thread and maybe for something close to the time you've specified.  That time *will* be in multiples of the system quantum--so, what you specify cannot possibly be exact.  If other threads of higher priority are doing work, it's less likely that your thread will be given processor time at a granularity close to the time you've suggested.